# How to save a SaverDef as protobuff in Tensorflow

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, tensorflow

Saving a `GraphDef`  can that's returned from calling `as_graph_def()` to `graph.pb` is done with `tf.train.write_graph`. However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to save off a `SaverDef` to `saver.pb` Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you can call SerializeToString() on the SaverDef object. This will get you a string representation that you can write to a file. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#standard-message-methods

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!